# How to access the nltk/wordnet Synset object?

Tags: python, nltk

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn 

print (wn.synsets('pretty')[0])
```

This code returns:

> Synset('pretty.s.01')

However, I can't seem to be able to do anything with this class. Is there anyway to extract the 'pretty.s.01' string from the Synset so that I can compare it in an if statement?

Comment: http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html Has a full list of things you can do with Synset objects....Do you want to do "anything" with the object (not class, btw) or are you specifically looking to pull out 'pretty.s.01'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> s = wn.synsets('pretty')[0]
>>> s.lemma_names() #call the method to extract list
['pretty']
```

Note that this gives a *list* of lemmas; I'm not sure when you'd get multiple, but it seems to be possible.

If you want to find out about other operations on a `Synset`, then call `help` or `dir` on it in the interpreter.

Comment: How would one call the `help` or `dir` to find out about other methods for the `Synset` object? Or is there documentation somewhere?

Comment: um, `help(s)`, `help(s.lemma_names)`?

Comment: I got no output with python 3.5 for `s.lemma_names` but `s.lemma_names()` works

Answer (score 3):

You can use .name() method for this:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn 

print (wn.synsets('pretty')[0].name())
```

Result is `pretty.s.01`

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple answer...at least it works for me:
 Just use `str()` to turn the Synset object to string, for example

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
s = wn.synsets('pretty')[0]
print str(s)[8:-2]
```

and it will return 
`'pretty.s.01'`